# How to change permissions of a folder inside System32 in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, security, ntfs

I need to programmatically remove "create file" and "create directory" permissions on a directory inside System32 directory for a group `"NT AUTHORITY\\INTERACTIVE"`.

To do this, I wrote following code:

```
        string windir = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("systemroot");
        string redirectionFolder = (windir + "\\System32\\Tasks2");
        MessageBox.Show(redirectionFolder);
        FileSystemAccessRule Tasks = new FileSystemAccessRule("NT AUTHORITY\\INTERACTIVE", FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories | FileSystemRights.CreateFiles, AccessControlType.Deny );
        DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = new DirectorySecurity(redirectionFolder, AccessControlSections.Group);
        dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(Tasks);
        Directory.SetAccessControl(redirectionFolder, dirSecurity);
```

When I run this code on a folder `C:\Tasks2`, it works.

But when I run it on `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks2`, I get the `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException` exception. Running the app as administrator doesn't help.

What can I do in order to change permissions of a directory inside System32 directory in C#?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks2` really does exist, the most likely explanation is that you are being caught out by the [file system redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187.aspx). You have a 32 bit process and the file system redirector converts `system32` into `SysWOW64`. And so whilst you think you are looking for `C:\Windows\System32\Tasks2`, you are actually looking in `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Tasks2`.

Compile your program as 64 bit. Or use `C:\WINDOWS\SysNative`.

Comment: +1, or use `C:\WINDOWS\SysNative` if compiling for 64-bit is too difficult.

Comment: Yes, @vcsjones that's an option but I have to say that I've never had much luck with `C:\WINDOWS\SysNative`.

Comment: The only thing that bugs me about it is, it's only ever present if the file system re-director is kicking in. It would be nice if it was there all the time (always points to System32 regardless of bitness). Speaking of which, another option is to [temporarily disable file system redirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365743(v=vs.85).aspx) for that particular operation.

Comment: @vcsjones That other option is a minefield. It's a global switch that can have appalling results. I would never recommend that. 64 bit is the way to go. Stop running inside the emulator.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to compile for x64! Tasks2, it's just a directory for test.

Comment: It Works! Thanks a lot!